# How to add a Image loaded to a picture box in C# windows forms to a SQL database table

Tags: c#, sql

I need to add that image loaded to the database table which I created in SQL

```
new BL_Gallery().insertGallery(new ML_Gallery()
    {
        ImageName = txtName.Text,     
        Image = pictureBox1.Image;   // I'm getting an error.
    });

XtraMessageBox.Show("Image Added !", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
this.Close();
```

Comment: are u using entity framework or ado.net?

Comment: Im using entity framework

Comment: so convert image object into base 64 string and insert to  your  table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the byte array (byte[]), then use Convert.ToBase64String():

```
byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"image file path");
string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

To convert:

```
var img = Image.FromStream(new 
MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)));
```